# Parse app using huge (2+GB) storage size in PFFileStaging folder

Tags: ios, parse-platform

We're using Parse in our iOS app and we've discovered that our app is using an enormous amount of space -around 2.3GB in some devices- in storage. After downloading app data to my Mac, I've realized almost all of that data is the cached images in a folder called `PFFileStaging`, it contains highest resolution PNGs of all the `PFFile`s that the user has viewed in our app, ever. How can we disable this behavior, at least limit it? Is that the intended behavior? I heavily doubt using GBs of space is the intended behavior. Is this a bug?

Comment: What caching policies are you using?

Comment: @soulshined nothing. whatever the default is.

Comment: The default is to ignore cache (supposed to) try forcing it with `kPFCachePolicyIgnoreCache`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not cache related (as per Parse's engineers: "*this is used to ensure that no concurrent modification happens to the file after you request uploading*").

They're planning to implement automatic trimming of `PFFileStaging` folder on every app start (as per road plan this should appear in next version 1.8.2).

See the the whole thread on [GitHub](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/18).

Comment: Just to let you know, 1.8.2 Parse SDK is out and works well for me. Check the above link to GitHub for more details on how to trigger the cleaning routine.